# If $\phi$ is a linear functional on $C(X)$ such that $\| \phi\|=\phi(1),$ why is $\phi$ is positive?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Suppose $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional on $C(X)$ such that $\phi(1)=1 \| \phi\|$. Why is $\phi$ positive?

To show that $\phi$ is positive we want to consider $f \geq 0$ and show that $\phi(f) >0$.

I was told that we can apply $\phi$ to $f \pm in$ and $f-n$ for a large $n$. But I don't see how this shows that $\phi$ is positive.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f \geq 0$  and let $M=\sup \{f(x): x\in X\}$. Then $\|M-f\|\leq M$ since $f(x) \in [0,M]$ for all $x$. If $\phi(f)$ is real we can finish the proof as follows:

$M-\phi (f)=\phi(M-f) \leq \|\phi\| \|M-f||\leq M$. Thus $\phi (f) \geq 0$.

To show that $\phi (f)$ is real consider  following:

$|\phi (f) \pm in|=|\phi(f \pm in)|\leq \|f\pm in\|\leq \sqrt {M^{2}+n^{2}}$.

If $\phi (f)=a+ib$ with $a,b$ real then this gives $a^{2}+(b+n)^{2} \leq M^{2}+n^{2}$ or $a^{2}+2bn \leq M^{2}$. This is true for all $n$ and  hence $b=0$ and $\phi (f)=a \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm just wondering if we still need to apply $\phi$ to $f \pm in$.

Comment: @Catcher I had assumed that $\phi (f) \in \mathbb R$. This requires a proof. I have edited my answer.