# Showing that this hermitian functional is positive

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-algebras

Let $\rho$ be a hermitian functional on $C(X)$ where $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff space. Suppose $\|\rho\|=\rho(1)$. Then show that $\rho$ is a positive linear functional on $C(X)$. Part of the problem was to specifically use a theorem that shows that $\rho$ can be written as a difference of linear functionals $\rho^+$ and $\rho^-$. The second part which is the one that I am stuck on asks us to do it without this theorem. This is problem 3.5.45 of Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras. Volume I: Elementary Theory
Richard V. Kadison and
John R. Ringrose.

I figured that an easy way to show this would be to show that if $f\geq 0$. Then $\rho(f)=|\rho(f)|$. However, when I tried this, I required the fact that $\rho$ was multiplicative. I'm not sure if there is enough information to show that $\rho$ is multiplicative. Any suggestions on different approaches or showing that $\rho$ is multiplicative?

For those interested here is what I did:

Assume $f\geq 0$. Then

$|\rho(f)|^2=\rho(f(x))\overline{\rho(f(x))}=\rho(f(x))\rho(\overline{f(x)})=\rho(f(x)\overline{f(x)})$ if $\rho$ is multiplicative.

$=\rho(|f(x)|^2)=\rho(f(x)^2)=\rho(f(x))^2$ again assuming $\rho$ is multiplicative.

I'm not sure where the fact that $\|\rho\|=\rho(1)$ comes in. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\rho$ is rarely multiplicative. It is a real valued measure such that  $\sup_{\|f\|_\infty=1}|\int fd\rho|=\rho(X),$ and you must derive that $f\ge0\implies \int fd\rho\ge0.$ (That is: *if* you are allowed to use the version of [Riesz-Markov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) for hermitian linear functionals.)

Comment: Note that this theorem holds for any unital $C^*$-algebra, not only the commutative ones, i.e. not only the $C(X)$'s for some compact Hausdorff $X.$ But a more specific duplicate is: [If $\phi$ is a linear functional on $C(X)$ such that $\| \phi\|=\phi(1),$ why is $\phi$ is positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086388).